# pre-commit.com post-checkout hook fails after modifying files

Tags: pre-commit.com

I have a post-checkout hook that substitutes the new branch name into some skeleton files in the "main" branch of the repository.  This seems to cause `pre-commit` to indicate failure when it does what I intend, though this is normally correct behavior.  Is there an option I'm missing?  Can I tell `pre-commit` that any file modification by this hook is acceptable?

I see "The hook must exit nonzero on failure or modify files" [in the documentation](https://pre-commit.com/#creating-new-hooks), and my hook does exit with an exit code of 0.

Comment: there isn't an option for that -- modifying checked in files like that seems odd

Comment: Thanks. I've chosen to use branches to separate my code and configuration for many projects while retaining a tight coupling between them. It's supposed to be a shadow of [cookiecutter](https://www.cookiecutter.io/), but multiple repos are overkill in this situation. Each branch is for a separate project and needs some template substitution before being used.

Comment: that sounds like a bad solution to a problem that doesn't really exist